# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED

Tags: javascript, ajax, requisição

Venho precisando fazer uma requisição síncrona e no resultado vem me dando esse erro.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.

A ideia desse código é fazer com que execute uma chamada depois a outra

```
function requisicaoSincrona(categoria, callback){
     xmlhttp = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    values = {"modulo":modulo,"categoria":categoria};
    myJsonString = JSON.stringify(values);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = respond;

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "classes/getData.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(myJsonString);
    //xmlhttp.abort();
    //como o código executado na volta da requisição é a função respond, chamamos o callback aqui
    function respond() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            x = document.getElementsByClassName('terceiraEtapa');
            x[0].innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        //verifica se uma função foi de fato passada, para então chama-la
        if(callback){
            callback.call();
        }
    }
}
function pegaSuporte(){
    requisicaoSincrona(9);

}
  requisicaoSincrona(6,pegaSuporte)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando não inicializas uma variável ela fica no escopo global e pode ser modificada por código em sítios diferentes sem deixar rasto. Isso gera erros muito difíceis de detectar e é "proibido" segundo regras de boas práticas.

Inicializa a variável com `const` ou `var` se precisas de suportar browsers antigos.

A minha sugestão é :

```
function requisicaoSincrona(categoria, modulo, destino, callback) {
  var xmlhttp = null;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }
  var values = {
    modulo: modulo,
    categoria: categoria
  };
  var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(values);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = respond;

  xmlhttp.open('POST', 'classes/getData.php', true);
  xmlhttp.send(myJsonString);
  //xmlhttp.abort();
  //como o código executado na volta da requisição é a função respond, chamamos o callback aqui
  function respond() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      destino.innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    //verifica se uma função foi de fato passada, para então chama-la
    if (callback) callback.call();
  }
}
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('terceiraEtapa')[0];
requisicaoSincrona(6, modulo, x, function() {
  requisicaoSincrona(9, modulo, x);
});
```